# I don't know how to get a value from a column with conditions on others columns

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I had to get the name of the Pokemon from the Dataframe who has the most higher attack ('name' represents a column and 'attack' too) for each type (for example water or fire etc) I write down this code :

```
PokDf.select('name').filter(PokDf.groupby('type1').agg({'attack'='max'})).show()
```

PokDf is DataFrame.

Sample:

```
+----------+-----+------+
|      name|type1|attack|
+----------+-----+------+
| Bulbasaur|grass|    49|
|   Ivysaur|grass|    62|
|  Venusaur|grass|   100|
|Charmander| fire|    52|
|Charmeleon| fire|    64|
| Charizard| fire|   104|
|  Squirtle|water|    48|
| Wartortle|water|    63|
+----------+-----+------+
```

I don't know how to deal with it. Once I run this line, it doesn't work. Anybody could help me please ?

Comment: Please provide reproducible example data and output. It would help others to answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a **`window`** to compute the **`max over a partition`**, and then **`filter on attack=max`** and then **`select`** your **`name`** column.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w=Window().partitionBy("type1")
df.withColumn("max",F.max("attack").over(w))\
  .filter('attack=max').select("name").show()

#+---------+  #output based on sample data above.
#|     name|
#+---------+
#| Venusaur|
#|Wartortle|
#|Charizard|
#+---------+
```